# Difference b/w saving a file with .html extension and .htm extension?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a difference b/w saving a file with .html extension and .htm extension?
I saved a notepad file with the following code:

```
     <html>
       <head>
     <title>last page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       document.write("hey");
       </script>
       this is a line of text
        </body>
        </html>
```

On running the file in both browsers i.e firefox and chrome i couldn't run the file with .htm extension but the one with .html runs okay. Also both the files display different icons w.here they are saved

Comment: `htm` is a 25% saving. Seriously though, what do you mean by "running the file"? Do you mean using the browser's menu to open the file, or are you just double-clicking the file names in your OS's file manager?

Comment: There is no difference. The .htm extension should work as well in both browsers as the .html extension.

Comment: Does the `.htm` file run if you put a `DOCTYPE` in your file, like valid HTML should have? Put `<DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of your file, before `<html>`. This may not make it work, as it should work already, but you should always have a `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: perhaps notepad saved it as `.htm.txt`?

Comment: Sounds like `htm` is not a registered file type in your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The `.htm` extension is a leftover from old Windows days, where files had to be 8.3 - a maximum of 8 characters long for the file name, and a maximum of 3 letters for the file extension.

The full extension for HTML files is `.html`, and there's no reason the full extension should not be used.